# I have this error when i ran a query ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

thank you for your time first of all.

I have this query but when I run it it takes a lot of time and I want to make it more efficient.

```
SELECT * FROM DSL 

WHERE ((
(SCENARI,PERIOD) in(
Select distinct
CAM11,CAM10
FROM
ETL)
AND
PROVENIENZA like '%RLF%'
)
OR
(
SCENARIO = (Select distinct CAM11 FROM ETL)
AND
PERIODO > (Select distinct CAM10 FROM ETL)
AND
CONT in (select distinct CAM17 from ETL where CAM31 is not null)
)
OR
(
SCENARIO = (Select distinct CAM11 FROM ETL)
AND
PERIODO = (Select distinct CAM10 FROM ETL)
AND
CONTO in (select distinct CAM17 from ETL where CAM31 is not null)
AND
cast(PERIODO as number) <> cast( substr(TO_CHAR(DATEUPD,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI'),4,2) as number) -1
AND
PROVENIENZA = 'INPUT'
)
OR
(
(SCENARI,PERIOD) in (
Select distinct
CAM11,CAM10
FROM
ETL)
AND
PROVENIENZA like '%SP%'
))) S
```

I tried this query after WHERE:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ETL t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAM11, CAM10
    FROM ETL
) t1 ON t.SCENARI = t1.CAM11 AND t.PERIOD = t1.CAM10
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAM17
    FROM ETL
    WHERE CAM31 IS NOT NULL
) t2 ON t.CONT = t2.CAM17
WHERE 
    (
        t.provenienza LIKE '%RLF%'
        AND t1.CAM11 IS NOT NULL
    )
    OR
    (
        t.PERIOD > t1.CAM10
        AND t1.CAM11 IS NOT NULL
        AND t2.CAM17 IS NOT NULL
    )
    OR
    (
        t.PERIOD = t1.CAM10
        AND t2.CAM17 IS NOT NULL
        AND CAST(t.PERIOD AS NUMBER) <> CAST(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(t.DATEUPD, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI'), 4, 2) AS NUMBER) - 1
        AND t.provenienza = 'INPUT'
    )
    OR
    (
        t.provenienza LIKE '%SP%'
        AND t1.CAM11 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

The main idea is to simplify the query and to make it more efficient. Clearly I did something wrong and maybe someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You seem to have your queries the wrong way round; the second one does not error, the first one does. Remove the `) S` from the end of that, for a start, as that is causing the ORA-00933. You then seem to have inconsistent names, oddities like `> (select distinct ...)` which will get multiple rows and error, data type conversions that look unneeded. I don't really see how that is supposed to be anything like the other query.

Comment: Try with for all your subqueries with "materialize" hint